Optional flag accepted only if particular other flag(s) provided
Scenario:

Flags -a 'thing1' and/or -b 'thing2' can be provided.
If either is provided, 'sub' flags -c and/or -d can be provided. * If -a and/or -b are not provided, -c and/or -d should be ignored/flagged as incorrect.

The code I currently have is:
import argparse

flag1 = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
flag1.add_argument("-a", "--alpha")
flag1.add_argument("-b", "--beta")

flag1a = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[flag1])

flag1a.add_argument("-c", "--charlie", action="store_true")
flag1a.add_argument("-d", "--delta", action="store_true")

args = flag1a.parse_args()

if args.alpha == None :
    print("Alpha not provided")
else:
    print("Alpha provided:", args.alpha)
if args.beta == None :
    print("Beta not provided")
else:    
    print("Beta provided:", args.beta)
print(args)

This works great when -a and/or -b are provided. -c and/or -d (or neither) are accepted, e.g.:
prog.py -a testa -c -d

Alpha provided: testa
Beta not provided
Namespace(alpha='testa', beta=None, charlie=True, delta=True)

But the issue is that -c and/or -d can be provided without -a or -b.
prog.py -c

Alpha not provided
Beta not provided
Namespace(alpha=None, beta=None, charlie=True, delta=False)

I was thinking about the subparsers feature, but these are flags, not commands. I had tried, but it got funny about using -c and -d.
Perhaps this is something I need to tackle outside of argparse, but wanted to reach out to the community to see if there is something I overlooked, a concept I've misunderstood.

i think that if it's locking some flags then it's a command

argparse does not provide much in the way of inter-argument tests.  mutually-exclusive is about all.  But as long as the default is None, you can test and constrain to your heart's delight (and user's confusion) after parsing.  Think about the usage/help you'll give yourself 6 months from now.

if args.alpha is None: is better than ==.  print(args] is handy during debugging.  You could ad a if a is None and b is None: if c is None or d is None: complain (flag1a.error(...). parents doesnt add any parsing power; it's more of convenience.

Thanks for the feedback, @hpaulj. Help will eventually be added in, this was just a quick/dirty way of showing what I have and what I'm experiencing. I'm thinking I'll have to setup conditional checking, but wanted to see if there was something I had overlooked. So if c or d are not None, but a and/or b are None, then complain. – edit: I've tried marking text as code within this comment, but I'm obviously not getting how it works :(

I was asking about usage because it can guide the setup   If it's hard to explain it may be too complicated. Ignoring the 'wrong' values may simpler.  But that may depend on what you think the user meant.   Ultimately the purpose of the parser is to understand as clearly as possible what the user wants.

I would suggest to code that yourself after parsing the arguments. for example: option a: do nothing, if -c or -d is ignored by your code anyway when -a or -b are not set, option b:  if not args.alpha and not args.beta: args.charlie = False; args.delta = False, don't error if they are set, but have your code explicitly set them to false, option c. : if not args.alpha and not args.beta: if args.charlie: raise Exception("you did not provide -a or -b, -c should not be set") error if -c is provided without -a or -b

I suggested 3 options to illustrate, obviously you may choose whatever action seems suitable to your case: print a warning rather than error, treat -c and -d differently ... you know what is relevant to your command line program
